ERROR: Module dnssd does not exist!
I migrated a ubuntu VM from 22 to 24.04. Everything went OK and I was able to RDP, however, whatever I try to install I get an issue for Apache2 as follows (I tried installing dnssd, same thing and error and operation terminates with an error)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rabbitmq-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 25,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package rabbitmq-server.
(Reading database ... 420176 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rabbitmq-server_4.0.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking rabbitmq-server (4.0.3-1) ...
Setting up rabbitmq-server (4.0.3-1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rabbitmq-server.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service.
Setting up apache2 (2.4.58-1ubuntu8.5) ...
info: Executing deferred 'a2enmod dnssd' for package libapache2-mod-dnssd
ERROR: Module dnssd does not exist!
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

 sudo apt-get install dnssd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dnssd

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-dnssd**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-dnssd is already the newest version (0.6-4build3).
libapache2-mod-dnssd set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ebtables g++-11 gcc-12-base gcc-12-base:i386 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gtksource-4 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gnome-themes-standard guile-2.2-libs
  kubectl libabsl20210324 libaio1 libappstream4 libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2
  libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libboost-filesystem1.74.0 libboost-iostreams1.74.0 libboost-locale1.74.0 libboost-regex1.74.0
  libboost-thread1.74.0 libbpf0 libcbor0.8 libcodec2-1.0 libcolamd2 libcolord-gtk1t64 libdav1d5 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdazzle-common libdns-export1110 libebook-1.2-20
  libebook-contacts-1.2-3 libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserverui-1.2-3 libfreerdp-client2-2t64 libfreerdp-server2-2t64 libfreerdp2-2t64 libgnome-todo
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgssdp-1.2-0 libgupnp-1.2-1 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgweather-3-16 libhawtjni-runtime-java libilmbase25 libio-prompt-tiny-perl libisc-export1105
  libjansi-native-java libjte2t64 libkate1 libllvm15t64 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmozjs-91-0 libmpdec3 libnfs13 libnsl-dev libopenexr25
  libopenh264-6 liborcus-0.17-0 liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libparted-fs-resize0t64 libperl5.34 libpoppler118 libpostproc55 libprocps8 libprotobuf23 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libqpdf28 libraw20 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2 libsmbios-c2 libsnapd-glib1
  libsrt1.4-gnutls libstdc++-11-dev libsuitesparseconfig5 libswresample3 libswscale5 libtirpc-dev libunistring2 libunistring2:i386 libvncserver1 libvpx7 libwinpr2-2t64 libx264-163
  libzxingcore1 linux-headers-5.15.0-113 linux-headers-5.15.0-113-generic p7zip p7zip-full perl-modules-5.34 python3-future python3-lib2to3 python3-lockfile python3-macaroonbakery
  python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339 python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal socat

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up apache2 (2.4.58-1ubuntu8.5) ...
info: Executing deferred 'a2enmod dnssd' for package libapache2-mod-dnssd
**ERROR: Module dnssd does not exist!**
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 installed apache2 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Even when I do
apt autoremove

I get the same error

Hi, can somebody respond please?
